# Matrix equation $HA + A^*H = -I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Given a matrix $A$, whose eigenvalues are $\lambda_i$ with $\Re(\lambda_i)\lt 0$, is there a matrix $H$ such that

$$HA + A^* H = -I$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix and $A^*$ is the adjoint matrix? If such a matrix $H$ exists, is it unique? Is it possible to write out an expression for $H$?

Please give small hints, but do not completely solve the problem for me.

Comment: Repost of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104125/ha-ah-e-matrix-equation-differential-equations

Comment: Shouldn't $H$ be positive definite?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo why do you think so?

Comment: Because you have a [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation).